# Prevent webpages from binding to certain keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, macos, safari

I'd like to stop webpages from binding to ⌥ (Option) only shortcuts.

E.g. these *can* be bound to:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- etc.

But these I want to prevent being bound to (so that their default comes into effect, I have set them up as dead keys/special character keys on my keyboard to type symbols I find important):

- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- etc.

Comment: What web pages are you going to that *modifies* system settings like key bindings?

Comment: @Allan idk what you mean by "System" settings, but one site that keeps frustrating me is Google docs because it binds to ⌥/

Comment: Your first one - Cmd-V -  is paste which is a system setting.  How is that being bound?

Comment: @Allan I don't know, I was making up examples

Comment: @Allan also, it seems entirely possible to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510129/how-to-disable-paste-ctrlv-with-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373424/how-to-detect-command-key-is-pressed-in-javascript-at-mac-os

Comment: It's not a biding...it's an intercept and an override.  In this case, there's nothing you can do because no matter what, the key press is what the site detects and reacts based on that, not what is normally sent by the system (macOS).

Comment: @Allan it's possible to stop the client's javascript from detecting keypresses (maybe not in safari as it currently is, but it's possible)

Comment: @theonlygusti Do you mind if you block *all* keybindings? Or do you want to only block option-only bindings?

Comment: @timothymh only option bindings

Answer (score 1):

I lightly edited some code from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/670040/101900) on Super User to make it prevent the capture of certain shortcuts which do use the Option key and do not use the Command key. You'll want to add the keycodes for any shortcuts you want to prevent binding to the keycodes list. I started it with the codes for the two examples in your question, `/` and `E` (it doesn't care if other modifiers are pressed or not).

You can install this to your browser using an extension such as Tampermonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Disable option shortcuts
// @description    Stop websites from highjacking keyboard shortcuts
//
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

// These are the keycodes for E and /. Find others to add by uncommenting the first alert line below and pressing that key.
keycodes = [69, 191];

(window.opera ? document.body : document).addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // alert(e.keyCode ); //uncomment to find more keyCodes
    if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.altKey && !(e.metaKey)) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // alert("Gotcha!"); //uncomment to check if it's seeing the combo
    }
    return false;
}, !window.opera);
```

Comment: I would like ⌘-⌥-/ to be bindable. If another modifier is pressed, it should do what the page says.

Comment: @theonlygusti It is! If the command key is pressed, this script will not do anything. It only prevents binding of combinations which (1) have Option pressed and (2) do not have Command pressed. If you also want to add Control to that list, you can add `&& !(e.ctrlKey)` to the `if` statement.

Comment: @theonlygusti Have you tried this yet? Is it lacking in any way?

Comment: I don't really want to have to install a userscript manager if it can be avoided so I was just waiting longer. I think though if nothing happens in another week I'll make my own Safari plugin with the capability to prevent any user-specified shortcut from being bound to.

Comment: Where does one input this code?

Comment: @2540625 “You can install this to your browser using an extension such as Tampermonkey.” It’s called a userscript, and there are various extensions that let you install them.

Comment: Where in TamperMonkey?

Comment: @2540625 Click the new script button (scroll icon with green plus) and paste it into the editor. You can also customize what websites it runs on via the Settings section, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic way to do this on macOS.

You could probably write a plugin for the specific browser(s) you want this functionality for - but no such specific plugin exists right now.

Comment: How would one do that?